# How to "sum" enumerables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to "sum" diverse enumerables when they are string mode?
per example like this? (well, I know this doesn't work.)

```
(( 'a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z')).to_a
```

note: 
I am asking about getting an array of string chars from a to z and from A to Z all together.
About string mode I mean that the chars will appears like ["a", "b", ..... , "Y", "Z"]

Comment: What is your expected result? An array of 52 elements (of all upcase and lowcase letters)?

Comment: yes. Something like that.

Comment: What would the expected output be? Are you asking how to lift the addition operation over the two `Enumerable`s? And what is "string mode"?

Comment: I am asking about getting an array of string chars from a to z and from A to Z all together. About string mode I mean that the chars will appera like ["a", "b", ..... "Z"]

Comment: Please don't hide crucial information like this away in a comment. Put it in the question, so one can see it. Now that you have finally produced an example of your desired output, it turns out that every single answer given so far is wrong, and you have wasted everybody's time by playing a guessing game.

Comment: @RadW2020 : in your note.. all together does it mean like "aA", "bB" ?

Comment: sorry my english but I mean that the chars will appears like ["a", "b", ..... "Z"]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `splat` operator:

```
[*('A'..'Z'), *( 'a'..'z')]
```

Comment: Even works without parenthesis: `[*'A'..'Z', *'a'..'z']`

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the updated question, this answer is no longer correct.

Comment: This is brilliant and works prefectly and elegantly for me. Sorry if my english have created misundertoods.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
[('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z')].map(&:to_a).flatten
```

Or this?

```
('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
```

Comment: `[('A'..'Z'), ('a'..'z')].flat_map(&:to_a)` is shorter ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the updated question, this answer is no longer correct.

Comment: It is correct for the pourpose of the array. You only need to swap the arrays to change the result. That is easy. The difficult is to figure out how to do this thing.

Answer (score 2):

Not answer but benchmarking of answers:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 100000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("flat_map   : ") { n.times do ; [('A'..'Z'), ('a'..'z')].flat_map(&:to_a) ; end }
  x.report("map.flatten: ") { n.times do ; [('A'..'Z'), ('a'..'z')].map(&:to_a).flatten ; end }
  x.report("splat      : ") { n.times do ; [*('A'..'Z'), *( 'a'..'z')] ; end }
  x.report("concat arr : ") { n.times do ; ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a  ; end }
end
```

Result:

```
#=>       user     system      total        real
#=> flat_map   :   0.858000   0.000000   0.858000 (  0.883630)
#=> map.flatten:   1.170000   0.016000   1.186000 (  1.200421)
#=> splat      :   0.858000   0.000000   0.858000 (  0.857728)
#=> concat arr :   0.812000   0.000000   0.812000 (  0.822861)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the updated question, this answer is no longer correct.

Comment: Why do you say that? All four options do the same and perfectly for the purpose of the question asked.

Comment: @RadW2020: Well, you changed your question to ask about the exact opposite order than you did before. When I wrote my answer and wrote that comment, your question asked about how to get the arrays in the reverse order. Now, your question asks about how to get them in the order they appear. Of course, anything written *before* you made that change will make absolutely no sense whatsoever anymore.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : Well, I could edit the question and put that the order is not important for the purpose of the array and then it will make sense again, I think people can understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the elements from the *first* `Range` to be at the *end* of the output `Array` and the elements of the *last* `Range` to be at the *beginning* of the output `Array`, but still keep the same order *within* each `Range`, I would do it like this (which also generalizes nicely to more than two `Enumerable`s):

```
def backwards_concat(*enums)
  enums.reverse.map(&:to_a).inject([], &:concat)
end

backwards_concat('A'..'Z', 'a'..'z')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['a'..'z'].concat(['A'..'Z'])
```

This is probably the quickest way to do this.

Comment: thats wrong. This is your output "a..zA..Z". concat is for strings.

Answer (score 0):

> About string mode I mean that the chars will appears like ["a", "b", ..... , "Y", "Z"]

To answer the above:

```
Array('a'..'z').concat Array('A'..'Z')
```